# Image source error in React Native: require expect exactly 1 literal string

Tags: react-native, require

Hi I have iumages in local path in react native and I'm trying to provide path as

```
 <ListItem
    roundAvatar
    avatar={<Avatar
        rounded
        source={require( '../../../public/images/'+props.item.ImageName+'.png')}
        title={props.item.cat_name}
    />}
    onPress={() => props.subscreen(props.item._id)}
    key={props.item._id}
    title={props.item.cat_name}
/>
```

But it shows error

[image]

on printing image path on console it shows string only. What can be other way around or where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables in a require, only a string, not a variable.
You need do this:

```
avatar={<Avatar
        rounded
        source={require( '../../../public/images/nameOfPic.png')}
        title={props.item.cat_name}
    />}
```

if you wanna choose a image you can do like this.

```
arrayImgs = [require('../../anyName1.jpg'), require('../../anyName2.jpg')];
...
 <ListItem
    roundAvatar
    avatar={<Avatar
        rounded
        source={isTrue?arrayImgs[0]:arrayImgs[1]}
        title={props.item.cat_name}
    />}
    onPress={() => props.subscreen(props.item._id)}
    key={props.item._id}
    title={props.item.cat_name}
/>
```

EDIT:

You can use URI for local images.

```
let imagePath = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/'+imageName+'.png'
...
<Image
              style={{width: '100%', height: 400}}
              resizeMode='contain'
              source={{imagePath}}
            />
```

this is a default path for a folder in your Android, try to use any image in your 'Pictures' folder.

Comment: I am using to display 100 images on 100 rows dynamically not itinerary two images.How can I achieve that?

Comment: So, if you have so much images you need use the 'uri',

Comment: let path = 'file://'+pathToResources+'/'+href+'.png';
source={{uri: path }}

Comment: You don't need convert, but you need to download or put the images in the cellphone in anyway.

Comment: 'file://'+'../../../public/images/'+props.item.ImageName+'.png' .. image not found... is there any error on path? if I import image with this path it works.

Comment: Using URI the image can't be in your project folder, but in any folder of your phone.

Comment: look this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#uri-data-images

Comment: And you need to know the path of file, I will show an example, wait

Comment: URI the image can't be in your project folder, but in any folder of your phone. But I have folder in my project folder only. where exactly should be pictures folder in android folder?

Comment: sadly you need to use something like the array's example, is hard for Android and iOS to index the images, so the guidelines say that you need to use a external way for a huge quantity of images or another assets.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
require(`../../../public/images/${props.item.ImageName}.png`)
```

The quotes are not the same type.